# Powershell - if and testpath with not Logic

Tags: powershell, if-statement

My Code is this:

```
If (Test-Path c:\temp\mysunnyday)
{
    New-Item c:\temp\mysunnyday -ItemType directory
}
Set-Location c:\temp\mypodcast
```

I wish to say `IF NOT TRUE`. How can I do that? I read this article

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_if_not.htm#Example_2:_PowerShell_If_-Not_Logic

and I tried with `-ne ! -not`

But nothing works. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your statement in another set of brackets and negate it:

```
If (!(Test-Path c:\temp\mysunnyday))...
```

Comment: `If ( -not (Test-Path c:\temp\mysunnyday))`  should also work. `!` is shorter